# Parse fixed-width files

Tags: perl, parsing

I have a lot of text files with fixed-width fields:

```
<c>     <c>       <c>
Dave    Thomas    123 Main
Dan     Anderson  456 Center
Wilma   Rainbow   789 Street
```

The rest of the files are in a similar format, where the `<c>` will mark the beginning of a column, but they have various (unknown) column & space widths. What's the best way to parse these files?

I tried using `Text::CSV`, but since there's no delimiter it's hard to get a consistent result (unless I'm using the module wrong):

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new();
$csv->sep_char (' ');

while (<FILE>){
    if ($csv->parse($_)) {
        my @columns=$csv->fields();
        print $columns[1] . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you object to the "parsing" tag?  This is a parsing problem.  That you require a solution in Perl does not mean it is not a parsing problem.

Comment: because I don't want a general solution

Comment: maybe I misunderstood...I thought putting "parsing" in there would bring a whole bunch of solutions that aren't relevant to my situation (ie python, php, etc)....thx

Comment: I am going to guess there is one (or two or three or...) module(s) on CPAN for this? As far as the dynamic widths, just build the appropriate "templates" up dynamically once the headers are read -- or *does the width depend upon something absolutely insane like the max width of the data per column?*

Comment: @pst - See my answer. CPAN has a module that not only parses, but can determine width automatically for you (heuristically) :)

Comment: DataExtract::Fixed width does just this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As user604939 mentions, `unpack` is the tool to use for fixed width fields.  However, `unpack` needs to be passed a template to work with.  Since you say your fields can change width, the solution is to build this template from the first line of your file:

```
my @template = map {'A'.length}        # convert each to 'A##'
               <DATA> =~ /(\S+\s*)/g;  # split first line into segments
$template[-1] = 'A*';                  # set the last segment to be slurpy

my $template = "@template";
print "template: $template\n";

my @data;
while (<DATA>) {
    push @data, [unpack $template, $_]
}

use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper \@data;

__DATA__
<c>     <c>       <c>
Dave    Thomas    123 Main
Dan     Anderson  456 Center
Wilma   Rainbow   789 Street
```

which prints:

```
template: A8 A10 A*
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'Dave',
            'Thomas',
            '123 Main'
          ],
          [
            'Dan',
            'Anderson',
            '456 Center'
          ],
          [
            'Wilma',
            'Rainbow',
            '789 Street'
          ]
        ];
```

Answer (score 6):

CPAN to the rescue!

[DataExtract::FixedWidth](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DataExtract::FixedWidth) not only parses fixed-width files, but (based on POD) appears to be smart enough to figure out column widths from header line by itself!

Comment: BTW, the author hangs out here on SO once in a while.

Comment: DVK++ =) thanks! DE:FW is also well tested with [tons of test input.](http://api.metacpan.org/source/ECARROLL/DataExtract-FixedWidth-0.09/t/data/)

Answer (score 3):

Just use Perl's [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) function. Something like this:

```
while (<FILE>) {
    my ($first,$last,$street) = unpack("A9A25A50",$_);

    <Do something ....>
}
```

Inside the unpack template, the "A###", you can put the width of the field for each A.
There are a variety of other formats that you can use to mix and match with, that is, integer fields, etc...
If the file is fixed width, like mainframe files, then this should be the easiest.

Comment: that's part of my question...the width of the field will change depending on the file that I feed it. Is there a way for unpack to detect the width from the header?